GraphDB API: question about import method
I am using GraphDB 10.8 (Free), and want to use the GraphDB API to import an RDF file into the default graph. I have been reading and trying out the API documentation, but I'm failing to run the import POST method. The error seems to be the file name of the import file. I initially used the /rest/repositories/importtest/import/server GET method to show the files available for import, and that works nicely. It gives a JSON package of information that I then used to build the import POST method, but no matter what I've tried for the filenames array property, I get the error:
File [path]/briefdata.rdf does not exist

To be clear, the file does exist, at /home/ianpiper/graphdb-import (which is the default location on the server) and it is world read-write. Actually, the file is found with the GET form of the method, so it seems like in the POST method I am just not providing the right form of the path leading to the file. Can anyone set me straight on this?
Thanks,
Ian.

The answer to this was not to use a path at all, but simply to put the filename into the fileNames array:
     "fileNames": [
    "briefdata.rdf"
  ]

It makes sense I suppose; GraphDB has the import folder /home/ianpiper/graphdb-import already defined, so it only needs the filename.
